Steam, Vk и другие крупные сети, как реализована синхронизация данных в сети
уже не первый день у меня в голове всплывает вопрос, а как крупные социальные сети отображают нам в реальном времени актуальную информацию. Предположим тот же Steam, в эту же секунду им пользуется куча людей. Допустим у меня в моем списке будет друг, который живет на другой половине Земли. При входе в сеть он высвечивается у меня "В сети", с маленькой задержкой, а ведь у меня список друзей может быть очень большой. То есть, предположим что мой друг подключается к ГЕО сети кластеру территориально близко к нему. Далее сервер должен как-то знать что я нахожусь в сети и отправить ему эту информацию. Не будет же он перебирать весь его большой список друзей как и у меня. Возьмем например тот же вк. Друзей может быть 10 000, в реальном времени можно перейти на вкладку "Друзья онлайн" и увидеть друзей которые сейчас онлайн. Меня очень интересует устройство сети. Хочу реализовать этот метод обновления/синхронизации и поддержки актуальных данных в своем проекте. Есть источники где можно почитать про архитектуру таких гигантов как Google, Facebook, Instagram, Vk, Сбербанк и т.д.

Может вас интересуют брокеры вроде Kafka и RabbitMQ?

Перебираются не все друзья, а сразу выбираются из БД только те, которые онлайн, обычным селектом из базы. Хорошо проиндексированная база быстро работает на выборку. То, что там много серверов и они синхронизируются между собой - это уже другой вопрос.

"Есть источники где можно почитать про архитектуру таких гигантов как Google, Facebook, Instagram, Vk, Сбербанк и т.д." --- нет, конечно, т.к. для некоторых это может быть критичной информацией, которой могут воспользоваться недоброжелатели. Особенно в банковской сфере.  Они могут что-то общее использовать, как писали выше - Kafka, RabbitMQ, но не факт. Иногда что-то своё написанное, своя логика и  реализация и разработка.. Но как конкретно та или иная структура что-то использует - в публичном доступе нет. Общие инструменты - есть. Очереди, сокеты, подписка на событие и пр.
